# How to set up recurring migration through queries/script from SQL server(On-premise) to Azure SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, sql-agent

I need a help to sync the data on Azure SQL from SQL server(On-premise).

Available recourses:

1. 2 Database (SQL Server) on premise available on different server
2. Azure SQL database on cloud
3. Migration script/queries are ready to fetch data from on-premise sql server

Requirements:

4. Set up a scheduler which will run every 12 hours means two times in a day on Azure SQL.
5. In scheduler, using migration scripts data will be fetch from the On-premise SQL server and insert into Azure SQL Database.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most prevalent Azure SQL DB migration/replication features is [**`Azure Data Sync`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-data-sql-server-sql-database?view=azuresql).

There are two sorts of schedules: `Automatic` and `Manual`. **Automatic schedules function on time intervals**, with the lowest number being 5 minutes. The second kind is the manual schedule, which allows the user to conduct the sync anytime they want using the Azure Portal or PowerShell. The goal of this PowerShell workflow script is to do a one-time sync manually, then switch to automatic sync and configure Sync time intervals according to your preferences.

you can refer this links to setup data sync [Set up Data Sync in the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-sql-server-configure?view=azuresql), [Set up Data Sync with PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/scripts/sql-data-sync-sync-data-between-azure-onprem?view=azuresql)

**Reference:** [Schedule Data Sync with Azure SQL Database use an Automation account](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/schedule-data-sync-with-azure-sql-database-use-an-automation/ba-p/368988)